# Ionic serve doesn't run on devApp on IONIC4

Tags: ionic4, ionic-devapp

This question is to ionic 4 and I want to know how to run an ionic app using a real device.

i have this one on my command 
    [INFO] Development server running!

```
       Local: http://localhost:8100

       Use Ctrl+C to quit this process

[INFO] Browser window opened to http://localhost:8100!
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running:

```
ionic serve --address 0.0.0.0
```

Or use other address of your local machine (192.168 etc).